# Full text search works in mysql but not php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following in php:

```
public function myfunction($v){
//ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
$v=mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection,$v);
 $stmt=mysqli_prepare($this->connection,"SELECT * from TABLE WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST($v)");

    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows=array();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$row->column1,$row->column2);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

      $rows[]=$row;
      $row = new stdClass();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$row->column1,$row->column2);

    }

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);
print_r('this is a test');
print_r($rows);
}
```

This is searching a longtext column that has a fulltext index.....

Running this code (w/ the ini_set commented out) I get a memory size exhausted error. When I uncomment the ini_set part and increase the memory I get no output and no errors (not even 'this is a test' gets printed).

Why am I not getting any output (or at least an error statement) when I increase the memory? I have not adjusted my error reporting in php.

(Running the same statement directly in mysql (without increasing the memory limit) takes .0007 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you save all the records that mysql gave in your `$rows` array.

If the recordset is huge then you get that error.
Also your syntax with a double call of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$row->column1,$row->column2);`
 isn't that good looking